# need tcl progam for sorting (without lsort)

Tags: sorting, tcl

I Need tcl programm for sorting, but i should not use lsort operation.
i have tried this. but no luck

```
set list1 {1 6 5 4}
set list2 {}

for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $list1]} {incr i} {
    set temp [lindex $list1 $i] 
    for {set z [expr $i+1]} {$z < [llength $list1]} {incr z} {
        set temp2 [lindex $list1 $z]
        #puts "$temp,$temp2,$list1,$i,$z"
        #puts $temp2
        if {$temp < $temp2} {

        } else {
            puts "$i,$z"
            set list1 [lreplace $list1 $i $i $temp2]
                        puts "> $list1"
            set list1 [lreplace $list1 $z $z $temp]
                        puts ":: $list1"

        }
    }
}
puts $list1
```

Thanks
Ranjith

Comment: we don't write code for you, and if you can't explain HOW this code isn't working, we're not going to waste our time trying to GUESS what you want it to do.

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Merge_sort#Tcl

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can implement all sorts of sorting algorithms if you want. Just treat Tcl's lists like an array in any number of other languages:

- Create with `lrepeat` if necessary, though with a sorting algorithm you're usually given the list to sort.
- Read the value at a particular index with `lindex`.
- Write the value at a particular index with `lset`.

As a hint, here is **how to swap the elements at two indices**, `$i` and `$j`. It uses a temporary variable, `tmp`:

```
set tmp [lindex $list1 $i]
lset list1 $i [lindex $list1 $j]
lset list1 $j $tmp
```

Comment: “Sort without using `lsort`” sounds like homework, so I won't hand out the whole algorithm.